# Jquery Nice Form Validation Plugin

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, validation

I have found a nice form validation plugin in this website:http://formvalidator.net/index.html

While I was trying to implement server-side validation, the plugin doesn't seems to work. It states that it would send the url via POST method to the url that I have declared in the attribute data-validation-url.However when I tried to echo the post variable, it doesn't seems to show in the web browser.

Could someone help to look into it? Maybe I might have done something wrong somewhere. Apologies, I am quite new to programming! :)

Take a look at this page section:http://formvalidator.net/index.html#security-validators

FormValidate.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="form-validator/jquery.form-validator.min.js"></script>
<script>
$.validate
  ({
   modules : 'security',
   onModulesLoaded : function() 
 {
$('input[name="pass"]').displayPasswordStrength();
 }
  });
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <form action="" id='form'>
        <p>
           <label>User name:</label>  
 <input name="user" data-validation="server" data-validation-url="validateInput.php" />
        </p>

 <p>
   <label>Password:</label>
   <input  name="pass" data-validation="strength" data-validation-strength="2"   type="password">

</p>
<p><i>Hint: A strong password consists of 13 alphanumeric characters.</i></p>

 <label> Confirm password:</label>
<input name="pass_confirmation" data-validation="confirmation" type='password'>
 <p>
 <input type="submit">
 </p>
  </form>   
 </body>
 </html>
```

validate.php

```
<?php
 $response = array(
 'valid' => false,
'message' => 'Post argument "user" is missing.'
                  );

 if( isset($_POST['user']) ) {
    echo $_POST['user'] //value not echoed in the browser :/
                            }
 echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: add `method="POST"` in the `form` tag

Comment: where and exactly what message do you get about the `POST` method to be used ?

Comment: I tried but still it doesn't work. If you scroll down further to the source code provided, it did not add the method post on the form. It just basically get the url from the attribute data-validation-url. I believe this is because the plugin uses ajax to send over the url for processing at the server end.

Comment: paste the exact message.' uses ajax; - so what ?

Comment: "...The validation function will send a POST request to the URL declared in data-validation-url."

Comment: Those `<label>`s aren't associated with their `input`s. Use either `for` attributes or nest the `input`s inside the `label`s to fix the issue. See http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H44

Answer (score 0):

EDITED: I missed completely a slash in the input of the username, and that was the problem, test it now, now it fires the post request.

You only need to add method post on the form.

Try to use proper indentation it's easier to read and no one will blame you for doing it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-form-validator/2.1.47/jquery.form-validator.min.js"></script>
<script>
$.validate({
  modules : 'security',
  onModulesLoaded : function() {
    var optionalConfig = {
      fontSize: '12pt',
      padding: '4px',
      bad : 'Very bad',
      weak : 'Weak',
      good : 'Good',
      strong : 'Strong'
    };

    $('input[name="pass"]').displayPasswordStrength(optionalConfig);
  }
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
  <form action="/login" id='form'>
    <p>
      <label>User name:</label>  
      <input name="user" data-validation="server" data-validation-url="validateInput.php">
    </p>
    <p>
      <label>Password:</label>
      <input  name="pass" data-validation="strength" data-validation-strength="2"   type="password">
    </p>
    <p>
      <i>Hint: A strong password consists of 13 alphanumeric characters.</i>
    </p>

    <label> Confirm password:</label>
    <input name="pass_confirmation" data-validation="confirmation" type='password'>
    <p>
      <input type="submit">
    </p>
  </form>   
</body>
</html>
```

Check this out, seems to be working fine.

Good Luck.

Comment: Sorry about the indentation! I tried to add the method='post' but it still doesn't work. :/

Comment: copy my code sample and test if it works, you just need to change the action attribute in the form to your php endpoint. or just click Run code snippet to see it working, also I've changed the script src to use the cdn provided by them

Comment: Hmm...I still don't know why I can't get it to work. Sigh* Am i suppose to supply my '/+php file name' at the action attribute? Also,nothing happens when I run the code snippet and submit the form.

Comment: the input for username had a typo, that was the problem, check the snippet now, I just tested it and it works fine for the username and password..